# Exporting cpp code to python using cmake and boost

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, boost, cmake-gui

I have cpp library that I want to use in python. 
I succeeded in exporting it to python2 using boost.. 
now I want to make it work with python3..
I
Tried using 2to3 and it had problems in the parts where I used the functions that were exported.
I tried to export them the same way but changing to python3 in cmake GUI but it doesn't work..

What changes and were do I need to do in order to make it work in python3?

Answer (score 0):

We can do it by two ways.. 
the first one when we have setup.py file we can run 
Python3 setup.py bdist_wheel

The second option is to change in cmake GUI to python 3 and change to anaconda3 (I have python2 and 3 on the same computer and even when I chose python3 he takes anaconda2.. so I changed it)